# WebdriverIO SevereServiceErrror not stopping the test run

Tags: webdriver-io, testautomationfx, wdio

I have setup a [custom wdio service](https://github.com/AnglesHQ/angles-wdio-reporter/blob/master/src/integrations/wdio/AnglesWDIOService.ts) (as per the [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/customservices/)) which is used to create a build for the [Angles automation dashboard](https://angleshq.github.io/).

As part of this service I want to use the [SevereServiceError](https://webdriver.io/docs/customservices/#service-error-handling) when it is unable to create the build and stop the run. However in [my example test](https://github.com/AnglesHQ/webdriverio-example) it throws the error and simply continues the test run. See logs here:

```
2022-03-05T07:28:36.936Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2022-03-05T07:28:36.936Z INFO chromedriver: Start Chromedriver (/git/angles/webdriverio-example/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver) with args --port=9515 --url-base=/
2022-03-05T07:28:36.982Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
SevereServiceError: Unable to create a build due to connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000.
    at /Users/sergios/Documents/git/angles/webdriverio-example/node_modules/angles-wdio-reporter/src/integrations/wdio/AnglesWDIOService.ts:57:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async /Users/sergios/Documents/git/angles/webdriverio-example/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/utils.js:28:17
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Launcher.run (/Users/sergios/Documents/git/angles/webdriverio-example/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/launcher.js:86:13)

Continue...
2022-03-05T07:28:36.985Z INFO chromedriver: Starting ChromeDriver 98.0.4758.102 (273bf7ac8c909cde36982d27f66f3c70846a3718-refs/branch-heads/4758@{#1151}) on port 9515
2022-03-05T07:28:36.987Z INFO chromedriver: Only local connections are allowed.
```

You can run the example yourself by cloning [the example repo](https://github.com/AnglesHQ/webdriverio-example) and running `npm run test`.

**NOTE:** This should fail because it's looking for a local instance of [the Angles dashboard](https://angleshq.github.io/).

Any ideas why the SevereServiceError isn't stopping the test run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [updating wdio dependencies and ts-node and typescript](https://github.com/AnglesHQ/webdriverio-example/commit/d4647cafeec4730dfeebdca44c319008222dc91e) to current versions this issue has been resolved. The test run now stops when the SeverServiceError is thrown.